# attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: django, django-models

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/users/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
**attempt to write a readonly database**
Exception Location: C:\Users\parul\anaconda\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 396
Python Executable:  C:\Users\parul\anaconda\envs\MyDjangoEnv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\parul\\Desktop\\Djangoforms\\ProTwo',
 'C:\\Users\\parul\\anaconda\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\parul\\anaconda\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\parul\\anaconda\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\parul\\anaconda\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv',
 'C:\\Users\\parul\\anaconda\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 23 Dec 2020 16:14:46 +0000
```

Also, i checked the properties in db.sqlite3, all the permissions are checked...write permission also
can anyone help
using windows... i tried : cacls  *.*  /t  /e  /g  everyone:f
but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make permissions for the folder that contains the Database will solve the problem.
Also, you can run it as administrator to solve problem.

Comment: The folder containing the db.sqlite3 file has the write permission . Still it's not working

Comment: run cmd as admistrator